# Is $S$ connected?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, connectedness

> Let $f : \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary continuous function. Define $$S : = \left \{y \in \mathbb R\ \bigg |\ \text {there exists a sequence}\ \{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}\ \text {in}\ \mathbb R\ \text {such that}\ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty\ \text {and}\ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = y \right \}.$$ Can we say that $S$ is connected?

I have shown that $S$ is closed. Clearly $S \subseteq \overline {f(\mathbb R)}.$ But will it help anyway? Actually I want to use results like for any connected subset $A$ of a topological space if $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline {A}$ then $B$ is also connected. Here since $S$ is a closed set we need to find a connected set $A$ such that $S = \overline A.$ Can we always find such an $A\ $? Another thing which comes to my mind is the following $:$

We know that connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are the intervals. So we need to show that $S$ is an interval (in fact a closed interval). If $S$ is empty or a singleton then it is trivially connected. So WLOG let us assume that $a,b \in S$ with $a \lt b.$ Let $a \lt c \lt b.$ I have to show that $c \in S.$ Since $a,b \in S$ there exists sequences $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ both diverging to $\infty$ such that $f(x_n) \to a$ and $f(y_n) \to b.$ Choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $a \lt a + \varepsilon \lt c \lt b - \varepsilon \lt b.$ Since $f(x_n) \to a$ and $f(y_n) \to b$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $$f(x_n) \lt a + \varepsilon \lt c \lt b - \varepsilon \lt f(y_n).$$ Since $f$ is continuous then by intermediate value theorem there exists $z_n \in \left (\min \{x_n, y_n \}, \max \{x_n, y_n \} \right )$ for all $n \geq N$ such that $f(z_n) = c.$ Now consider a sequence $\{w_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ as follows $:$ $$w_n = \begin{cases} 1 & 1 \leq n \lt N \\ z_n & n \geq N \end{cases}$$ then $w_n \to \infty$ since $x_n,y_n \to \infty$ and $f(w_n) \to c.$ So $c \in S,$ as required. This shows that $S$ is an interval. Hence $S$ is connected.

Is my reasoning fine? Could anyone please have a look at it?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: As I understand it, $f(w_n) = f(z_n) = c$ for $n \ge N$. – The proof looks good to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $:$ $f(z_n) = c$ for all $n \geq N.$

Comment: IS $S$ closed set ?

Comment: Try Cantor's diagonal argument.

Answer (score 2):

> I have shown that S is closed. Clearly $S\subset \overline{f(\mathbb R)}$. But will it help anyway? Actually I want to use results like for any connected subset A of a topological space if $A\subset B \subset \overline A$ then $B$ is also connected. Here since $S$ is closed set we need to find a connected set $A$ such that $S=\overline A$. Can we always find such an A ?

I don't see any way of making this line of reasoning work as a proof here (although once we proved that $S$ is connected, $A= S$ works).

The other line of proof seems good to me.

Comment: IS $S$ a closed subset ?